# extracting contents from csv using java

Tags: java, xml, csv

I need a java program that would extract info from a .csv file and run commands on a sql bank.

I've made a program that is working great so far, but I've made it to work with .xsl by mistake and can't make it to work with a csv file

here is the code:

```
package teste3;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;



public class Teste3 {
       private String inputFile;
    String[][] data = null;
    String[][] user = null;
    public void setInputFile(String inputFile) 
    {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public String[][] read() throws IOException  
    {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        Workbook w;

        try 
        {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);



            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            data = new String[sheet.getColumns()][sheet.getRows()];
            user = new String[sheet.getColumns()][sheet.getRows()];

            int j = 11; 
            int a = 0;
            sheet.getColumns();
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) 
               {

                   Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                    data[0][i] = cell.getContents();
                    System.out.println(cell.getContents());


                }

            }


            j= 9;
            for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) 
               {


                   Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                    user[0][i] = cell.getContents();
                    System.out.println(user[0] [i]);





                }


        } 
        catch (BiffException e) 
        {
        }
    return data;
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Teste3 test = new Teste3();
        test.setInputFile("C:\\Users\\a0046059\\Documents\\teste.xls");
        test.read();
    }

}
```

the program is really simple because of my lack of skills.

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There are libraries that read/write csv files, you can check some examples here http://www.journaldev.com/2544/java-csv-parserwriter-example-using-opencsv-apache-commons-csv-and-supercsv